# Updating Font Awesome on wordpress theme

Tags: font-awesome

I am trying to upload a new version of [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) icons to a `Wordpress` theme that is already using the old version. I uploaded new files to the old `FontAwesome` location, but still, old icons are showing. The location is not changed - so I didn't change anything in any code. Basing on logic, everything should work properly since new files were uploaded.

Anyone have the idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the old images are cached somewhere? Perhaps in one of the following places:

- Wordpress (possibly via plugin?)
- Web server
- Web browser

I’d ensure that all caches are flushed, then check again.